# interpolation search array out of bounds

Tags: java, search

I am making a java program that uses the interpolation search below I have gotten from wikipedia. In my main program I have created an int array that will have 100,000 spots. Then I fill all those spots with random numbers and sort it. I then generate a random search key and call the function. I am also looping the function call 100 times each time with a different search key. When I do this I get an array out of bounds error on this statement if (sortedArray[mid] < toFind). The program works fine with an array with 10 spots, 100 spots, 1000 spots, but when I get to 100,000 I get the error. Do you know what I can do to fix this problem?

```
 public int interpolationSearch(int[] sortedArray, int toFind){
  // Returns index of toFind in sortedArray, or -1 if not found
  int low = 0;
  int high = sortedArray.length - 1;
  int mid;

  while (sortedArray[low] <= toFind && sortedArray[high] >= toFind) {
   mid = low +
         ((toFind - sortedArray[low]) * (high - low)) /
         (sortedArray[high] - sortedArray[low]);  

   if (sortedArray[mid] < toFind)
    low = mid + 1;
   else if (sortedArray[mid] > toFind)
    // Repetition of the comparison code is forced by syntax limitations.
    high = mid - 1;
   else
    return mid;
  }

  if (sortedArray[low] == toFind)
   return low;
  else
   return -1; // Not found
 }
```

Comment: You should log if mid is ever greater than the length of the array and see what the values of low, high and toFind are when this happens. Add this just before the if statement.

Comment: When I add  mid = Math.min(mid, sortedArray.length) just before if (sortedArray[mid] < toFind) it either goes out of bounds or runs infinite. In my main program when I have the array with 100,000 spots and put 100,000 sorted numbers in it, I make the search key a random number up to 100,000. If I only make the search key a random number up to 100 it will work perfectly. Do you have any idea why this is happening? Or how I can allow the search key to work when it is a random number up to 100,000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  overflowing the max value that can be stored in an int which is 2,147,483,647.

When calculating the numerator in your equation you are doing ((39258-0)*(99999-0)) which is 3,925,760,742.

If you change it to this you won't have this issue:

```
long numerator = (long)(toFind - sortedArray[low]) * (long)(high - low);
mid = low + numerator / (sortedArray[high] - sortedArray[low]);
```

I think you also need to change your while loop to be:

```
while (sortedArray[low] < toFind && sortedArray[high] >= toFind) {
```

Otherwise you have a situation where sortedArray[low] == sortedArray[high] == toFind

Then your equation reduces to

```
mid = low + (0 * (high - low)) / 0 = 0/0
```

Java allows division by zero. I'm not exactly sure what happens though, it may be that in this case mid = infinity or NaN.

Comment: should I add that when mid is declared ex: int mid=Math.min(mid, sortedArray.length) or in the while loop instead of  mid = low +
         ((toFind - sortedArray[low]) * (high - low)) /
         (sortedArray[high] - sortedArray[low]);  ?

Comment: Thanks for all your help you have given me. I was doing the math and I had a search key = 39258, low = 0, high = 99999, sortedArray[low]=0 and sortedArray[high] = 99998. When I do the math for the while loop it should be 0 + ((39258-0)*(99999-0)) / (99998 - 0) = 39258. The program tells me that this equals -3692 and thats out of bounds. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Yep use longs or doubles instead of ints. You are overflowing the max size of an int.

Answer (score 0):

You should be developing code like this in an IDE like Eclipse (there are others).  In Eclipse you can debug this program and instruct the debugger to stop whenever a particular exception (Like ArrayOutOfBoundsException) is thrown.  You can then see what line of code caused the error and you can see the value of each variable.  With that information it will be much easier to identify and fix the problem.